# How to get value is brand.brandName in select

Tags: java, reactjs, select, frontend

```
<Select defaultValue={"-----Select-----"} style={{ width: "35%" }}>              
              {brands.map((brand: any) => (
                <Option value={brand.id} key={brand.brandName}>{brand.brandName}</Option>
              ))}
            </Select>
```

- my original list
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nybXs.png)
- F12 and change display value
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JispT.png)
- After submit
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYpK8.png)

When i F12 and change display value to new value, and it not in brands. in terms of display i am adding with a brand that is not available but i am still getting the id of the original value. i want to check if the displayed value is available in my list but i can't get it. What solution for that.

Comment: `brand.brandName` isn't really a canonical thing everyone knows about, that's specific to your app alone as far as I can tell. Please show a [mcve] including the format of `brands` and  the rest of your component. Please show the definitions of `Select` and `Option`, or mention the UI lib they can be found in. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. Sorry about that. I'm interested in seeing your code, not screenshots of the app.